# What command can i use instead of `ListAccounts`

Tags: command-line-options

In documentation said: "listaccounts will be removed in a later version of Bitcoin Core"

https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#listaccounts

> In "See Also" section:
>
> GetAccount - Not return list accounts
>   GetAddressesByAccount [deprecated]
>   ListReceivedByAccount [deprecated]

Are we have a alternative command ?

Comment: `listunspent`??

Answer (score 1):

You can still use the same commands to get a list of accounts and addresses

```
getaddressesayaccount: returns a list of every address assigned to a particular account.

listreceivedbyaccount: lists the total number of bitcoins received by each account.
```

Or as a workaround you can try the trick with the following:

```
listaddressgroupings: lists groups of addresses that may have had their common ownership made public by common use as inputs in the same transaction or from being used as change from a previous transaction.

listtransactions "*" 1 0 true: List the most recent transaction from all accounts including watch-only addresses.
```

More info on the available commands to list accounts/addresses: https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference

Hope this helps,

kind regards.

*Cluster2k*

Comment: thx for the answer! I realized that I can set label(s) for all addresses get labels with `listlabels`
get addresses with `getaddressesbylabel` for each label

Answer (score 0):

> `listaddressgroupings` Returns all addresses in the wallet and info used
>   for coincontrol

it basically  returns output as a list contaning address and corresponding balance

```
[
  "2NCX68pyD9Hcp4FVtpoGYqG8GegDEiYBvNp",
  1.99939120
],
[
  "2NE6ee6nVjsmqTVy8WUqR9Krk84PH82KqV1",
  0.00000000
],
[
  "2NEPfREuzAZbVJNMfPR9gr8jfKCGZE24Xjw",
  42.99996200
]
```